# Firefox profile changing using command

Tags: firefox, batch-file

I want to switch between two firefox profiles online using bat file without closing my firefox. Is it possible? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) says:
"Firefox saves your **personal information** such as bookmarks, passwords, and user preferences in a set of files called your profile, which is stored in a separate location from the Firefox program files."

I don't think that is possible. Firefox reads files from the profile directory at start-up and writes them back when quit. If you would do it by hand you still need to tell Firefox to read the initialization files again. This could mess up all the profiles at the end I guess.

Why would that make sense? What do you want to do w/ it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch profiles without restarting Firefox.

However, you can run several copies of FF with different profiles simultaneously. I don't know what is your goal, but maybe this can help?

Command line:

`firefox -P <profile-name> -no-remote`

Be careful not to run more than one instance of Firefox with same profile. The `-no-remote` switch prevents a Firefox instance from knowing about other instances. If multiple instances access the same profile simultaneously, the profile can be corrupted.